# Split a list whose elements are multiple element lists

Tags: r, string, list, strsplit

Say I have a list `a` which is defined as:

`a <- list("aaa;bbb", "aaa", "bbb", "aaa;ccc")`

I want to split this list by semicolon `;`, get only unique values, and return another list. So far I have split the list using `str_split()`:

`a <- str_split(a, ";")`

which gives me

```
> a
[[1]]
[1] "aaa" "bbb"

[[2]]
[1] "aaa"

[[3]]
[1] "bbb"

[[4]]
[1] "aaa" "ccc"
```

How can I manipulate this list (using `unique()`?) to give me something like

```
[[1]]
[1] "aaa" 

[[2]]
[1] "bbb"

[[3]]
[1] "ccc"
```

or more simply,

```
[[1]]
[1] "aaa" "bbb" "ccc"
```

Comment: `unique(unlist(sapply(a, function(i) strsplit(i, ';'))))`

Comment: Hey @Sotos can you please submit this as an answer so I can accept? This works wonderfully.

Comment: Actually, this returns a result of class character when I need a list.

Comment: @Miha answer is what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `list()` with `unique()` and `unlist()` inside your list.

```
    # So first you use your code
    a <- list("aaa;bbb", "aaa", "bbb", "aaa;ccc")
    # Load required library 
    library(stringr) # load str_split
    a <- str_split(a, ";")
    # Finally use list() with unique() and unlist()
    list(unique(unlist(a)))
    # And the otuput
    [[1]]
    [1] "aaa" "bbb" "ccc"
```

Comment: you could use `strsplit(unlist(a))`, which works with `strsplit` from base R (no real need for `library(stringr)`

Comment: @Miha we have an "Rkoholiki"  slack going on. Drop me a line at romunov located at gmail if you would like to join us. This message will self destruct in XY minutes. :)

Answer (score 3):

One alternative in base R is to use `rapply` which applies a function to each of the inner most elements in a nested list and returns the most simplified object possible by default. Here, it returns a vector of characters.

```
unique(rapply(a, strsplit, split=";"))
[1] "aaa" "bbb" "ccc"
```

To return a list, wrap the output in `list`

```
list(unique(rapply(a, strsplit, split=";")))
[[1]]
[1] "aaa" "bbb" "ccc"
```